# Getting data from angular factory using BreezeJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, breeze

I'm working on implementing an Angular factory into a project I'm working on.

I've gotten routing working: ArtLogMain.js

```
var ArtLog = angular.module('ArtLog', ['ngGrid', 'ui.bootstrap']);

ArtLog.config(function ($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $routeProvider.when("/ArtLog", {
        controller: "ArtLogCtrl",
        templateUrl: "/Templates/ArtLog/Index.html"
    });

    $routeProvider.when("/ArtLog/:Id", {
        controller: "ArtLogEditCtrl",
        templateUrl: "/Templates/ArtLog/Edit.html"
    });

    $routeProvider.when("/ArtLog/Dashboard", {
        controller: "ArtLogDashBoardCtrl",
        templateUrl: "/Templates/ArtLog/Dashboard.html"
    });

    $routeProvider.otherwise("/");
});
```

Next I setup the Factory: ArtLogDataService

```
ArtLog.factory("ArtLogDataService", function ($q) {
    breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstance("modelLibrary", "backingStore", true);

    var _artLogView = [];
    var _artLogSingle = [];

    var _getArtLogById = function (Id) {

        var deferred = $q.defer();

        var manager = new breeze.EntityManager('breeze/BreezeData');
        var query = new breeze.EntityQuery().from('Project').where("Id", "Equals", Id);

        manager.executeQuery(query).then(function (data) {
            angular.copy(data, _artLogSingle);
            deferred.resolve();
        }).fail(function () {
            deferred.reject();
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    };

    var _getArtLogView = function () {

        var deferred = $q.defer();

        var manager = new breeze.EntityManager('breeze/BreezeData');
        var query = new breeze.EntityQuery().from('ArtLogView');

        manager.executeQuery(query).then(function (data) {
            //angular.copy(data.results, _artLogView);
            _artLogView = data.results;
            deferred.resolve();
        }).fail(function () {
            deferred.reject();
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    };

    return {
        artLogView: _artLogView,
        artLogSingle: _artLogSingle,
        getArtLogView: _getArtLogView,
        getArtLogById: _getArtLogById
    };
})
```

The the Controller: ArtLogController.js

```
function ArtLogCtrl($scope, ArtLogDataService) {
    $scope.ArtLogData = ArtLogDataService;
    $scope.editableInPopup = '<button id="editBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="edit(row)" >Edit</button>';

    ArtLogDataService.getArtLogView();

    $scope.edit = function (row) {
        window.location.href = '/ArtLog/' + row.entity.Id;
    };

    $scope.gridOptions = {
        data: ArtLogDataService.artLogView,
        showGroupPanel: true,
        enablePinning: true,
        showFilter: true,
        multiSelect: false,
        columnDefs: [
            { displayName: 'Edit', cellTemplate: $scope.editableInPopup, width: 80, pinned: true, groupable: false, sortable: false },
            { field: 'ArtNum', displayName: 'Art Number', resizable: true, pinned: true, groupable: false, width: '100px' },
            { field: 'CreateDate', displayName: 'Date Created', cellFilter: "date:'MM-dd-yyyy'", pinnable: false, width: '110px' },
            { field: 'ArtCompletionDue', displayName: 'Art Comp Due Date', cellFilter: "date:'MM-dd-yyyy'", pinnable: false, width: '160px', enableCellEdit: true },
            { field: 'DaysLeft', displayName: 'Days Left', pinnable: false, width: '90px' },
            { field: 'RevisionNum', displayName: 'Rev Number', pinnable: false, width: '100px' },
            { field: 'Status', displayName: 'Status', pinnable: false, width: '80px' },
            { field: 'Template', displayName: 'Template', pinnable: false, width: '190px' },
            { field: 'Driver', displayName: 'Driver', pinnable: false, width: '160px' },
            { field: 'AssignedTo', displayName: 'Assigned To', pinnable: false, width: '160px' },
            { field: 'BuddyArtist', displayName: 'Buddy Artist', pinnable: false, width: '160px' }
        ],
        filterOptions: {
            filterText: "",
            useExternalFilter: false
        }
    };
}
```

I set a breakpoint on ArtLogDataService.getArtLogData and I see the call fire. I also see the query run and data is returned, but When I look at the ArtLogDataService object returned from the factory it always shows Array[0]. The data never seems to bind to artLogView.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your network callback from Breeze is not part of the Angular update loop.  Angular doesn't know that your data changed, so the watcher on the view binding never gets updated.

You need to wire in a `$scope.$apply()` call when your data comes back.  This will cause the bindings to notice the change in the data and update.

Perhaps something like this:

```
ArtLogDataService.getArtLogView().then(function() {
    $scope.$apply();
});
```

If you do everything from within Angular, you never need to call `$scope.$apply`, because anything that can mutate data (events, network responses, timeouts, etc) will get handled by Angular (via `$http` and `$timeout`, etc) and `$apply` will automatically get called.  It is in these situations where the data gets changed by an event from outside of Angular that `$scope.$apply` is necessary.

Hope this does it for you!

Comment: I've tried using $http.get("/breeze/BreezeData/ArtLogView").then... and I still get the same result. From the looks of it the data is never being copied to _artLogView.

Comment: Never mind it is copying... the promise from .then is not working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You do not ... and should not ... use $q.deferred in your query callbacks. The Breeze EntityManager methods already return promises ... $q promises when you use the *Breeze.Angular* module as explained in the documentation and demonstrated in samples such as "Todo-Angular".

Get rid of your hand-rolled promises and you won't need $apply either.

Should be something like this:

```
// Create or acquire the manager ONCE for the lifetime of your data service
// Todo: more testable to use a separate "entityManagerFactory" service
//       to get your manager.
var manager = new breeze.EntityManager('breeze/BreezeData');

var _getArtLogView = function () {

    return breeze.EntityQuery.from('ArtLogView')
                 .using(manager).execute()
                 .then(success)
                 .catch(fail); // only if you have something useful to do here when it fails

    function success(data) { return data.results; }

    function fail(error) { 
       // some kind of logging or useful error handling;
       // otherwise don't bother with fail here
       return $q.reject(error); // so caller sees it
    }
};
```